# Thread Safe Python Client Server Service

Tags: python, python-3.x, thread-safety, server, client

I had like to get some feedback about my Thread Safe Python Client-Server example.
Is it really thead-safe?
Do you see any dead-locks or other thread-safe problems?
https://github.com/icarpis/PyThreadSafeClientServer

```
# Server
import socket
import sys
import threading
import select

class ServerConnection():

    def __clientThread(self, callback, connection, client_address):
        try:
            inputs = [ connection ]
            outputs = [ ]
            timeout = 1
            while self.startClient:
                readable, writable, exceptional = select.select(inputs, outputs, inputs, timeout)
                if not ((readable or writable or exceptional)):
                    if (not self.startClient):
                        break
                    continue

                if (not self.startClient):
                    break

                for sock in readable:
                    data = sock.recv(16)
                    if (data):
                        callback(client_address, data)
        except Exception as e:
            print ('Server: ', e)
        finally:
            print("Exiting Client Thread")

    def __listenerThread(self, callback, numOfAllowedConnections):
        try:
            self.sock.settimeout(0)
            self.sock.setblocking(0)
            self.sock.listen(numOfAllowedConnections)
            print ('Server: Waiting for a connection...')
            read_list = [self.sock]
            timeout = 1
            while self.startListener:
                readable, writable, exceptional = select.select(read_list, [], [], timeout)
                if not ((readable or writable or exceptional)):
                    if (not self.startListener):
                        break
                    continue

                connection = None
                connection, client_address = self.sock.accept()
                connection.setblocking(0)
                self.mutex.acquire()
                if (self.startListener and connection):
                    self.connections.append(connection)
                    print ('\nServer: client connected:', client_address)
                    t = threading.Thread( target=self.__clientThread, args=(callback, connection, client_address) )
                    self._connectionThreads.append(t)
                    t.start()
                self.mutex.release()
        except Exception as e:
            print (e)
            self.Close()
        finally:
            print("Exiting Listener Thread")

    def __init__(self):
        self._listenerThread = None
        self.connections = []
        self._connectionThreads = []
        self.mutex = threading.Lock()
        self.sock = None
        self.callback = None
        self.numOfAllowedConnections = None

    def Open(self, ip, port, callback, numOfAllowedConnections):
        try:
            self.mutex.acquire()
            if (self.sock):
                return False

            self.sock = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_STREAM)
            self.callback = callback
            self.numOfAllowedConnections = numOfAllowedConnections
            server_address = (ip, port)
            self.sock.bind(server_address)
            print ('Creating socket on %s port %s' % self.sock.getsockname())
            self.startListener = True
            self.startClient = True
            self._listenerThread = threading.Thread( target=self.__listenerThread, args=(self.callback, self.numOfAllowedConnections, ) )
            self._listenerThread.start()
            return True
        finally:
            self.mutex.release()

    def Close(self):
        self.mutex.acquire()
        try:
            if (self.startListener == False):
                return False

            self.startListener = False
            if (self._listenerThread):
                try:
                    self._listenerThread.join(3)
                except Exception as e:
                    pass

            self.startClient = False
            try:
                for connection in self.connections:
                    connection.close()
            except Exception as e:
                pass
            self.connections = []

            for t in self._connectionThreads:
                try:
                    t.join(3)
                except Exception as e:
                    pass

            self._connectionThreads = []
        finally:
            self.mutex.release()
            return True

    def SendDataAll(self, data):
        try:
            self.mutex.acquire()
            print ('Server: sending "%s"' % data)
            for connection in self.connections:
                connection.sendall(data)
            return True
        except Exception as e:
            print(e)
            return False
        finally:
            self.mutex.release()

    def SendData(self, con, data):
        try:
            self.mutex.acquire()
            if con in self.connections:
                print (con.getpeername(), 'Server: sending "%s"' % data)
                con.sendall(data)
            return True
        except Exception as e:
            print(e)
            return False
        finally:
            self.mutex.release()

    def GetNumOfConnections(self):
        try:
            self.mutex.acquire()
            numOfCon = len(self.connections)
            return numOfCon
        finally:
            self.mutex.release()

    def GetConnection(self, index):
        try:
            conn = None
            self.mutex.acquire()
            conn = self.connections[index]
            return conn
        except IndexError:
            return None
        finally:
            self.mutex.release()


def cb(client_address, data):
    print (client_address, 'server received "%s"' % data)
    pass

def main():
    import sys
    serverConnection = ServerConnection()
    serverConnection.Open('localhost', 5000, cb, 3)

    print("\nPress Enter to continue...\n")
    sys.stdin.flush()
    sys.stdin.read(1)

    serverConnection.SendDataAll(bytes("Itay3", encoding='utf8'))

    numOfCon = serverConnection.GetNumOfConnections()
    print ("\nConnections: ", numOfCon)
    con = None
    if (numOfCon > 0):
        con = serverConnection.GetConnection(0)
    if (con):
        serverConnection.SendData(con, bytes("Itay4", encoding='utf8'))


    print("\nPress Enter to Exit...\n")
    sys.stdin.flush()
    sys.stdin.read(1)

    serverConnection.Close()
    pass

if __name__ == "__main__":
    main()


# Client
import socket
import sys
import threading
import select

class ClientConnection():

    def __init__(self, ip, port, callback):
        self.mutex = threading.Lock()
        self.sock = None
        self.ip = ip
        self.port = port
        self.callback = callback
        self.clientThread = None
        self.connect = False

    def __clientThread(self):
        try:
            inputs = [ self.sock ]
            outputs = [ ]
            timeout = 1
            while self.connect:
                readable, writable, exceptional = select.select(inputs, outputs, inputs, timeout)
                if not ((readable or writable or exceptional)):
                    if (not self.connect):
                        break
                    continue

                if (not self.connect):
                    break

                for sock in readable:
                    data = sock.recv(16)
                    if (data):
                        self.callback(self.sock.getsockname(), data)
        except Exception as e:
            print (self.sock.getsockname()[1], e)
        finally:
            print(self.sock.getsockname()[1], "Exiting Client Thread")

    def Connect(self):
        try:
            self.mutex.acquire()
            if (self.connect):
                return False
            self.connect = True
            self.sock = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_STREAM)
            server_address = (self.ip, self.port)
            print ('Client: connecting to %s port %s' % server_address)
            self.sock.connect(server_address)
            #self.sock.setblocking(0)
            t = threading.Thread( target=self.__clientThread)
            self.clientThread = t
            self.clientThread.start()
            return True
        except Exception as e:
            print (e)
            return False
        finally:
            self.mutex.release()

    def Disconnect(self):
        try:
            self.mutex.acquire()
            if (not self.connect):
                return False

            self.connect = False
            if (self.clientThread):
                try:
                    self.clientThread.join(3)
                except Exception as e:
                    pass
            if (self.sock):
                self.sock.close()
            return True
        finally:
            self.mutex.release()

    def SendData(self, data):
        try:
            self.mutex.acquire()
            if (not self.connect):
                return False
            if (self.sock):
                print (self.sock.getsockname(), 'Client: sending "%s"' % data)
                self.sock.sendall(data)
                return True
        except Exception as e:
            print(e)
            return False
        finally:
            self.mutex.release()

def cb1(address, data):
    print (address, 'Client1: received "%s"' % data)
    pass

def cb2(address, data):
    print (address, 'Client2: received "%s"' % data)
    pass

def main():
    client1 = ClientConnection('localhost', 5000, cb1)
    if (client1.Connect()):
        client1.SendData(bytes("Itay1", encoding='utf8'))
    if (client1.Connect()):
        client1.SendData(bytes("Itay1", encoding='utf8'))

    client2 = ClientConnection('localhost', 5000, cb2)
    if (client2.Connect()):
        client2.SendData(bytes("Itay2", encoding='utf8'))

    print ("\nPress Enter key to exit...\n")
    sys.stdin.flush()
    sys.stdin.read(1)
    client1.Disconnect()
    client2.Disconnect()
    pass

if __name__ == "__main__":
    main()
```